# Removing class / styles onclick

Tags: jquery, css

Ive got a point with some code that Im writng where I need to remove the validation errors once you click on either of the input boxes. But when I use standard removeClass they dont have the desired affect as it stops me from being able to submit again.

You can see what i mean here : http://jsfiddle.net/5V7Uv/5/

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="/whatmask_output/">
    <div id="sectioncol">
        <label for="input-whatmask">whatmask</label>
        <input type="text" name="input-whatmask" id="input-whatmask"
        size="22" />
    </div>
    <div id="sectioncol">
        <label for="input-whois">whois</label>
        <input type="text" name="input-whois" id="input-whois" size="22"
        />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" "whatmask_input" id="btn-search" align="right"
    />
</form>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var hasError = false;
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    var searchReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\/\.]+$/;
    if ($("#input-whatmask").val() != '' && $("#input-whois").val() != '') {
        alert('Enter only one field at a time.');
        return false;
    }
    if (hasError) return false;
    if ($("#input-whatmask").val() != '') {
        if (!searchReg.test($("#input-whatmask").val())) {
            $("#input-whatmask").addClass("errorinput").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid value.</span>');
            hasError = true;
            return false;
        }
    } else if ($("#input-whois").val() != '') {
        if (!searchReg.test($("#input-whois").val())) {
            $("#input-whois").addClass("errorinput").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid value.</span>');
            hasError = true;
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert('No values entered!');
        return false;
    }
});
$("#input-whatmask, #input-whois").click(function () {
    $("#input-whatmask, #input-whois").removeClass("errorinput");
    $("#input-whatmask, #input-whois").removeClass("error");
    $("#input-whatmask, #input-whois").val('');
    if ($(this).hasClass('errorinput')) {
        $(this).next().remove();
        $(this).removeClass("errorinput");
        hasError = false;
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hasError) return false;
```

This line looks like the offender, as your `hasError` variable gets set to true after the first run through (if there are errors, of course), and doesn't get set back to false.

try adding `hasError = false` after this line:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
```